# PowerDNS forward requests

Tags: networking, dns, powerdns

I want to switch from `bind` to `PowerDNS`.
My setup works just fine for resolving queries for which my DNS is authoritative, but I cannot find the setting on how to forward requests that yield NXDomain to another server, e.g. Google DNS (8.8.8.8).

I have done research and some of it points to using `PowerDNS-Recursor`. I'm unsure how I would connect PowerDNS and PowerDNS recursor. Furthermore, this setup seems to be a lot more complicated than using `bind`.